# Split php mysql data into 20 rows per column

Tags: php, mysql

I want to split the data from php mysql into 20 rows per column. Below is my code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id[] = $row['id'];
}
for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
    echo '<table><tr>';
    for ($j = 0; $j < (count($id)-1)/20; $j++) {
        echo '<td>'.$id[$i + $j * 20].'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr><tr>';
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

Let's say I have 21 rows, and the code only output 20 rows, and the 21th row is missing.

And if there are 22 rows (as long as the remainder after divided by 20 is more than or less than by 1), there is `undefined offset 22, undefined offset 23.....` errors.

There is something wrong with the inner `for` loop, but I cannot fix it. How can I fix this error?

Comment: and why not Using Pagination???

Comment: Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: @ajshort, thanks for the [reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php#Hcom48268). `array_chunk()` works fine. I hope to fix my dummy code too, as it can increase my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

i can't post comment (for +50 rep) and add some comment here

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$id[] = $row['id'];
}
for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
    echo '<table><tr>';
    for ($j = 0; $j < (count($id)-1)/20; $j++) {
        echo '<td>'.$id[$i + $j * 20].'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr><tr>';
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

i don't know why use second `for`

but in for condition you define 20 time run for `for`

this code maybe help you

```
echo '<table>'
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$id[] = $row['id'];
}
for($i = 0; $i <= 20; $i++) {

    echo '</tr><td>'.$id[$i].'</td><tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

and this is 21 time run `for` with `<=`